# Stirling Number 1st kind in polynomial expression

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I came across the following proofwiki page: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Stirling_Numbers_of_the_First_Kind/Signed

In definition 2, author states that:

> Signed Stirling numbers of the first kind are defined as the polynomial coefficients $s(n,k)$ which satisfy the equation $x^\underline{n} = \sum_k{s(n,k)x^k}$ where $x^\underline{n}$ denotes the *nth* falling factorial of x.

Why? How was this polynomial expression derived? It just states a definition, and provides no proof.

Is there a proof for this?

Comment: I assume you want to prove that definitions 1 and 2 are equivalent. Just expand $x^\underline{n+1}=(x-n)x^\underline{n}$ and match coefficients.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, or does OP want to know why the absolute values of the coefficients count permutations by cycles? I'm voting to close as unclear until OP states which two definitions they want to connect.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the combinatorial definition of $s(n,k)=(-1)^{n-k}c(n,k)$, where $c(n,k)=$ # {permutations in $S_n$ with k cycles}. Then the equation $x(x-1) \dots (x-n+1) = \sum_k s(n,k) x^k$ equivalent to $$x(x+1)\dots (x+n-1) = \sum_k c(n,k)x^k.$$
Now this equation has a combinatorial interpretation, both sides are counting the following objects:
$$\#\{(\pi,f):\pi \in S_n, f:\{\text{cycles of  } \pi\} \to [x]\}, \text{ where } [x]:=\{1,2,\dots,x\}.$$

RHS should be pretty clear. To see that the LHS is counting the above objects, you can think with the following steps:

1. Put the first 1, and choose one number from [x] -- $x$ choices
2. For 2, you have two choices: one is to start a new cycle, and choose one number from [x]; or join the cycle with 1 -- $x+1$ choices
3. repeat, until you have put all n numbers into a cycle...